# Edge clique cover algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, intersection, clique, clique-problem

I am trying to write an algorithm that computes the edge clique cover number (the smallest number of cliques that cover all edges) of an input graph (undirected and no self-loops). My idea would be to

1. Calculate all maximal cliques with the *Bron-Kerbosch* algorithm, and
2. Try if any 1,2,3,... of them would cover all edges until I find the
   minimum number

Would that work and does anyone know a better method; is there a standard algorithm? To my surprise, I couldn't find any such algorithm. I know that the problem is NP-hard, so I don't expect a fast solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on the similar problem 2 years ago and I've never seen any **standard** existing approaches to it. I did the following:

1. Compute all maximal cliques.
   [MACE](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/codes.htm) was way better than
   Bron-Kerbosch in my case.
2. Build a constraint-satisfaction problem for determining a **minimum number of cliques** required to cover the graph. You could use [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), [Minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/), [MIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) tools to do so. Which one to pick? It depends on your skills, time resources, environment and dozens of other parameters. If we are talking about proof-of-concept, I would stick with Minizinc.

A bit details for the second part. Define a set of Boolean variables with respect to each edge, if it's *value == True*, then it's covered, otherwise, it's not. Add constraints that allow you covering sets of edges only with respect to each clique. Finally, add variables corresponding to each clique, if it's == True, then it's used already, otherwise, it's not. Finally, require all edges to be covered **AND a number of used cliques is minimal**.

Answer (score 2):

I would gather maximal cliques as you do now (or perhaps using a different algorithm, as suggested by [CaptainTrunky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49145938/47984)), but then use [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).  This won't guarantee a speedup, but will often produce a large speedup on "easy" instances.

In particular:

- Instead of trying all subsets of maximal cliques in increasing subset size order, pick an edge uv and branch on it.  This means:

  - For each maximal clique C containing uv:

    - Make a tentative new partial solution that contains all cliques in the current solution
    - Add C to this partial solution
    - Make a new subproblem containing the current subproblem's graph, but with all vertices in C collapsed into a single vertex
    - Recurse to solve this smaller subproblem.
- Keep track of the best complete solution so far.  This is your *upper bound* (UB).  You do not need to continue processing any subproblem that has already reached this upper bound but still has edges present; a better solution already exists!
- It's best to pick an edge to branch on that is covered by as few cliques as possible.  When choosing *in what order* to try those cliques, try whichever you think is likely to be the best (probably the largest one) first.

And here is an idea for a lower bound to improve the pruning level:

If a subgraph G' contains an [independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) of size s, then you will need at least s cliques to cover G' (since no clique can cover two or more vertices in an independent set).  Computing the largest possible IS is NP-hard and thus impractical here, but you could get a cheap bound by using the 2-approximation for Vertex Cover: Just keep choosing an edge and throwing out both vertices until no edges are left; if you threw out k edges, then what remains is an IS that is within k of optimal.

You can add the size of this IS to the total number of cliques in your solution so far; if that is larger than the current UB, you can abort this subproblem, since we know that fleshing it out further cannot produce a better solution than one we have already seen.